# Generic Differential Equation for Oberth Effect

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, energy-conservation, rocket-science

In Wikipedia article about [Oberth Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect) there is an example of calculation in a simple case when the differential equation is not required. In non-English versions of this article (for example, [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effet_Oberth)) there is a differential equation
$$\frac{\mathrm dE_k}{\mathrm dt}=F\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}$$
but it does not contain speed and if I try to add it, it does not work or I get simple kinematics result $v=v_0+aT$.

This is how I tried to solve this differential equation.
$$\mathrm dE_k=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm d(\frac{mv(t)^2}{2})}{\mathrm dt}=Fv(t)$$

$$\frac{m}{2}\frac{\mathrm d(v(t)^2)}{\mathrm dt}=Fv(t)$$

$$\frac{m}{2}2v(t)\frac{\mathrm d(v(t))}{\mathrm dt}=Fv(t)$$

$$m\frac{\mathrm d(v(t))}{\mathrm dt}=F$$

and solution for this equation is $v=v_0+\frac{F}{m}T=v_0+aT$, which is just a classical kinematics equation and does not include Oberth effect at all. Looks like I am missing something in this derivation, but I could not understand what exactly.

If I take equation for the speed from [Oberth Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect) Wikipedia Article, then I have

$$v=\Delta v\sqrt{1+\frac{2v_0}{\Delta v}}$$

here I mean $v_0=V_{esc}$. They consider the case where time is small, then I can put it like this $\Delta v=aT$, then I will get

$$v=aT \sqrt{1+\frac{2v_0}{aT}}$$

if I make a graph of these 2 speed formulas $v=aT \sqrt{1+\frac{2v_0}{aT}}$ and $v=v_0+aT$ depending on $v_0$, then I see that kinematics speed higher then Oberth speed and I do not understand anything now :)

[image]

green is Oberth Speed on the graph and red is Kinematics Speed. acceleration $a=100$, time $T=0.1$.

My question is how to calculate the final speed of the rocket $v$ in the vacuum, if rocket initial speed is $v_0$, rocket engine produces constant thrust $F$ for the longtime $T$ (for example 10 hours). As I understand due to initial speed and Oberth effect final speed $v$ is not simple kinematics equation,
$$v=v_0+aT=v_0+\frac{F}{m}T$$
where $a$ - acceleration, $F$ is force and $m$ is mass.

I also would like to consider a very simple case: no gravity exists, no air, the thrust force is constant and mass is not changing. Mass is not changing I mean I do not use fuel for the engine, let's imagine theoretically, that my engine is something else, like a solar sail or I have a constant external fuel supply, that keep the rocket mass always the same, etc.

Comment: I tried to read both links, but do not read French.  I do understand the equations and it looks like (1) the relationship they are using is related to power, and (2) F is a force, and is dv/dt.  It almost looks like they are deriving a work energy relation.  My question to you is what do you mean by "but it does not contain speed and if I try to add it, it does not work or I get simple kinematics result v=v0+aT"?  Why is that a problem.

Comment: @ggcg I put derivation in my question. I miss something there but I could not understand what.

Comment: I think you have an error going to the last line.  Shouldn't a factor of v(t) cancel out?

Comment: @ggcg Yes, it is true, I will fix it (just typo), but the final solution is mathematically correct $v=v_0+aT$ is correct. And according to wikipedia article in case of Oberth Effect speed should be more than $v=v_0+aT$. There should be some physical mistake somewhere in between.

Comment: I get it.  If I think of anything useful I'll post.  Thanks for helping me understand your question.

Comment: I think I see a possible issue (but I am partly guessing).  In the solution you posted from another source is delta(v) a differential change in velocity?  If so I think T is an arbitrary large time.  Hence v-v0 is not an infinitesimal.  Could that be causing the missmatch?